# How to get full link text with Scrapy

Tags: python, html, scrapy

I've use scrapy to get datas from webpage.And I encountered a problem as below.

```
<li>
<a href="NEW-IMAGE?type=GENE&amp;object=EG10567">
<b>
man
</b>
X -
<i>
Escherichia coli
</i>
</a>
<br>
</li>
```

In webpage,the record's name looks like this:
[image]

I want to get the content (e.g.:**man X-Escherichia coli**) in the `<a>` tag and don't want to get other tags. And Here is my code:

```
def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath('//ul/li/a[contains(@href,"NEW-IMAGE")]')
    base_url = "http://www.metacyc.org/META"
for site in sites:
    item = MetaCyc()
    name_tmp = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('text()').extract())
    item['Name'] = unicode(name_tmp).encode('utf-8')
    item['Link'] = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('@href').extract())
    yield item
```

I have tried to convert the **unicode** to **utf-8**, but the results still looks like this:

```
{"Link": ["NEW-IMAGE?type=GENE&object=EG10567"], "Name": "[u'X -']"}
```

Sometimes there will have some character missing in the records.
So I want to know how to get the complete and correct format data from HTML code.

Comment: Converting Unicode to UTF-8 doesn't make much sense; UTF-8 *is* Unicode. Your result doesn't match the HTML, could you show the real HTML that the result is referring to?

Comment: Sorry,this one is correct **{"Link": ["NEW-IMAGE?type=GENE&object=EG10567"], "Name": "[u'X -']"},**, you can see the name of it isn't complete

Comment: I'll edit the question for you; try to make sure all the data is relevant. Unicode doesn't have anything to do with this.

Comment: Thank you! But how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use [XPath's `normalize-space()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space)

> The normalize-space function returns the argument string with whitespace normalized by stripping leading and trailing whitespace and replacing sequences of whitespace characters by a single space. Whitespace characters are the same as those allowed by the S production in XML. If the argument is omitted, it defaults to the context node converted to a string, in other words the string-value of the context node.

```
>>> html = """<li>
... <a href="NEW-IMAGE?type=GENE&amp;object=EG10567">
... <b>
... man
... </b>
... X -
... <i>
... Escherichia coli
... </i>
... </a>
... <br>
... </li>"""
>>> import scrapy
>>> selector = scrapy.Selector(text=html)

>>>
>>> links = selector.xpath('//li/a[contains(@href,"NEW-IMAGE")]')
>>> for link in links:
...     item = {}
...     item['Name'] = link.xpath('normalize-space(.)').extract_first()
...     item['Link'] = link.xpath('@href').extract_first()
...     print(item)
... 
{'Link': u'NEW-IMAGE?type=GENE&object=EG10567', 'Name': u'man X - Escherichia coli'}
>>>
```

Comment: I've tried this method, and I got almost ordered data,but there is a problem. Some character seems can't get correctly. e.g: The data in the webpage is 'β-1,4-D-mannosyl-N-acetyl-D-glucosamine degradation',and the data that i've got is '{"Link": ["NEW-IMAGE?type=PATHWAY&object=PWY-7586"], "Name": "\u03b2-1,4-D-mannosyl-N-acetyl-D-glucosamine degradation"},'. As you can see, the character **β** is incorrect. So how to solve this problem?

Comment: `u'\u03b2'` is not incorrect, it's how Python2 represents `β`. Try it in your python interpreter: `>>> u'β'` you'll get `u'\u03b2'`. How you export this Unicode data will matter then, whether it's JSON or XML or something, the conversion will happen then, for your next tool in the chain to interpret. Working with Unicode strings in Python as much as you can is recommended. Only when exporting would you need to encode the data for other tools.

Comment: So there is no method to print β in python, only when I continue to deal with the data should I consider this problem?

Comment: if you use `print` in the interpreter, it works: `print(u'\u03b2')` you get "β". But printing a dict for example, with show a representation of it and its strings: `print({"test": u'\u03b2'})` will show `{'test': u'\u03b2'}`

Comment: The Unicode data in the strings handled by Python in your script _is_ correct, you should not consider this a problem. Exporting the data for further consumption, outside of Python, has to be done eventually, but it's not a problem, but something to do with care, e.g. choosing the encoding. Using JSON (e.g. using `scrapy crawl myspider -o items.json`) should work fine.

Comment: uh..I have used `scrapy crawl myspider -o items.json`,and I still get an '\u03b2' instead of "β".So is this right?

Comment: @Coding_Rabbit Yes, it is also a valid JSON representation of β. You don't need to worry about it. It's the responsibility of whatever is using the data from the JSON file to display the unicode character correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get text of`a` tag and its child's you need to use `//text()` instead of `text()`

Try this:

```
name_tmp = map(unicode.strip, site.xpath('//text()').extract())
```

You can use another module `html2text` to get only text of a particular tag.

```
import html2text
htmlconverter = html2text.HTML2Text()
print htmlconverter.handle(''.join(name_tmp))
```

Comment: Sorry,I've tried this method,but the result becomes more disordered.

Comment: Can you give the output ?

Comment: I just want to get the content in the tag, If I use your method, I'll get so many irrelevant datas

Comment: It looks like this **window.location.reload(true);\n      }\n  }EG10567);", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "hide", "", "", "", "show operations", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "OPERATIONS", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ** and I don't know where it begins and ends.

Comment: Can you provide the url which you are scraping ? It's difficult to understand what you are asking without proper html.

Comment: metacyc.org/META/substring-search?type=NIL&object=man&quickSearch=Quick+Search

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the content (e.g.:**man X-Escherichia coli**) in the `<a>` tag and don't want to get other tags.

Part of the problem is that the text is not all contained in the `<a>` tag. Some of it is nested in the `<i>` tag **underneath** the `<a>` tag. To get the full link text as a string:

```
item_name = " ".join([word.strip() for word in sel.xpath('//li/a[contains(@href,"NEW-IMAGE")]//text()').extract() if len(word.strip())])  
# => item_name = 'man X - Escherichia coli'
```

The `//a//text()` means to recursively grab **all text** under all the `<a>` tags and their children in the document. Your `sel.xpath('//ul/li/a[contains(@href,"NEW-IMAGE")]/text()').extract()` would get "Some text"

```
<a href="../">Some text</a>
```

But would omit "And some more here" inside the `<b>` tags:

```
<a href="../">Some text<b>And some more here</b></a>
```